# Set Scope to recursive on list view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, caml-query

I'm trying to view only items without folders, here is my code to create listview

```
Items = function () {
    return {
        "Title": "Items",
        "DefaultView": "false",
        "Hidden": "false",
        "RowLimit": "30",
        "Query": "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy>",
        "ViewFields": [               
            {
                "Name": "Modified"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Editor"
            },
            {
                "Name": "_UIVersionString"
            }
        ]
    };
}
```

any idea how to set scope to Recursive... I'm working on SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try

"Scope" :1

```
DefaultValue = 0, Recursive = 1, RecursiveAll = 2, FilesOnly = 3
```

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx)